# Cut string with awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a string like that

```
key2|ex|am||ple
```

I'd want to get `example`. I want to get the part after the first pipe and without the other pipes.

For the moment I'm using `awk -F"|" '{print $2,$3,$4,$5}'` but it's not a good solution.

Comment: Why is it not a good solution?

Comment: It's not a good solution because the string can contains more pipes. Just an example.

Comment: Ah, ok.  That's the type of information that quality questions on Stackoverflow include - a description of input data, and the desired output.  And (as you included) an example or two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing this with a *C style for loop*

```
 echo 'key2|ex|am||ple' | awk -F'|' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf("%s", $i)}'
 example
```

Comment: printf is a builtin, not a function, so the () aren't doing what it looks like they're doing. Also, you need to add a `; print ""` to get the newline.

Comment: @EdMorton, nothing wrong with the parentheses: ["The entire list of arguments may optionally be enclosed in parentheses."](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html#Basic-Printf)

Comment: It's just unnecessary and misleading and I think almost all of the people who use them don't know that so IMHO it's worth pointing out.

Answer (score 8):

```
cut -d '|' -f 2- <<< "$string" | tr -d '|'
```

I'd write the awk solution this way

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS="" '{$1=""; print}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set the output field separator and unset the first field:

```
$ echo 'key2|ex|am||ple' | awk -v FS="|" -v OFS="" '{ $1 = "" ; print }'
example
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` and `tr`:

```
echo "key2|ex|am||ple" | sed 's/[^|]*|//' | tr -d '|'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/^[^\|]*\|//g;' your_file
```

Updating after the comment from @Ed

```
perl -F"|" -ane 'shift @F;print "@F"' your_File
```

Comment: That command would only remove up to the first |, it would not remove the rest of the |s.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple substitution on a single line and so a good application for sed:

```
$ echo 'key2|ex|am||ple' | sed -e 's/[^|]*|//' -e 's/|//g'
example
```

or if your sed supports EREs:

```
$ echo 'key2|ex|am||ple' | sed -r 's/^[^|]*[|]|[|]//g'
example
```

or the equivalent in awk (all awks support EREs):

```
$ echo 'key2|ex|am||ple' | awk '{gsub(/^[^|]*[|]|[|]/,"")}1'
example
```